# Problems with a list…

Tags: python, list, arraylist, list-comprehension

I am new in Python and I need to access a csv file that I have in a folder. This is not a problem:

open(‘C:\Users\Directory\companies.csv’)

I have tried this:

```
from csv import reader
# read csv file as a list of lists
with open('companies.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
# pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
# Pass reader object to list() to get a list of lists
list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)
print(list_of_rows)
```

OUTPUT

```
[['Company', 'Departments', 'Employess'],
['A', 'Marketing', '200'],
['B', 'Sales', '300’],
['C', 'HR', '15'],
['D', 'Logistics', '500'],
[‘A’, ‘Admin’, ‘15’],
[‘A’, ‘Research’, ‘30’],
[‘B’, ‘COffice’, ‘150’],
[‘C’, ‘Transporte, ‘200’],
[‘B’, ‘IT’, ‘200’],
[‘B’, ‘Gorg’, ‘12’]]
```

I am unable to obtain total number of Company ‘B’ departments and a new list that includes the number of departments in company A with more than 20 employees. I tried this:

```
new_list = [x for x in companies if Company = A' and 'Departments' > 20]

def total_elements(companies):
    count = 0
    for element in companies:
        count += 1
    return count

print("the total number is: ", total_elements(new_list))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is very broad, and does not show what you have or what you want. This makes it difficult to help you. Could you provide some samples of input and output, and preferably what you have tried so far ?  Read through [this page on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help you get more answers, which help yourself in the end.

Comment: Your question now actually boils down to "How do I parse list of lists in python".  There are plenty of [examples](https://pythonexamples.org/python-list-of-lists/) available.